# How to decrypt AES encrypted String in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: laravel, flutter, dart, encryption, aes

I have a string that was encrypted in Laravel PHP.
The encryption function is as below.

```php
public function getEncryptedString()
{
    try {
            $m2 = Crypt::encryptString('Thismessagewillbeencrypted', 'theencryptionkey');
        return response()->json([
            'm2' => $m2 ? $m2 : null,
        ], 200);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Something went wrong',
            'error' => $e->getMessage()
        ], 400);
    }
}
```

the Flutter/dart is as below.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:pointycastle/export.dart';

Uint8List aesCbcDecrypt(Uint8List key, Uint8List iv, Uint8List cipherText) {
  assert([128, 192, 256].contains(key.length * 8), 'Invalid key length.');
  assert(128 == iv.length * 8, 'Invalid IV length. IV must be 128 bits');
  assert(
    128 == cipherText.length * 8,
    'Invalid cipherText length. cipherText must be 128 bits.',
  );

  // Create a CBC block cipher with AES, and initialize with key and IV

  final cbc = CBCBlockCipher(AESEngine())
    ..init(false, ParametersWithIV(KeyParameter(key), iv)); // false=decrypt

  // Decrypt the cipherText block-by-block

  final paddedPlainText = Uint8List(cipherText.length); // allocate space

  var offset = 0;
  while (offset < cipherText.length) {
    offset += cbc.processBlock(cipherText, offset, paddedPlainText, offset);
  }
  assert(
    offset == cipherText.length,
    'Decryption process did not process the entire cipherText.',
  );

  return paddedPlainText;
}

void decrypter() {
  const encryptedString =
      'eyJpdiI6IjFLc001N25UNzhQNXVMOGxHMGZzeEE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVmU0SGVVL0xFQUtCeW83NkVSSXpOZDRXWUV2allZTEg0c3J4aTJNV1BkST0iLCJtYWMiOiI2Yjk2MGQ3NzAzOTIwMjM5YTc5NTEwMjM2NWFlNDM1MTYwZDI5NzBjNjE4MWQzN2Q0OTE4NmZjNDUxZjNjZGUwIiwidGFnIjoiIn0=';

  const key = 'theencryptionkey';

  final json = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(base64Decode(encryptedString)));

  final decodedKey = base64Decode(key);
  final decodedIV = base64Decode(json['iv'] as String);
  final decodedCipherText = base64Decode(json['value'] as String);

  // Ensure cipherText has the correct length
  final cipherText =
      decodedCipherText.sublist(0, 16); // Take the first 16 bytes (128 bits)

  final result = aesCbcDecrypt(decodedKey, decodedIV, cipherText);

  print(base64.encode(result));
}
```

the **encryptedString** is the response String I am getting when **Thismessagewillbeencrypted** is encrypted with **theencryptionkey** key.
This was of course to test the process.

but While testing to decrypt the encrypted string in a flutter dart code, I keep getting different errors. I can't understand what I am doing wrong.

Any guide on how to decrypt would help?

I am using [pointycastle](https://pub.dev/packages/pointycastle) package, and following [this](https://github.com/bcgit/pc-dart/blob/master/tutorials/aes-cbc.md).

Comment: `encryptedString` is Base64 decoded a JS object containing Base64 encoded IV (`1KsM57nT78P5uL8lG0fsxA==`) and ciphertext (`Ve4HeU/LEAKByo76ERIzNd4WYEvjYYLH4srxi2MWPdI=`). Decryption with `theencryptionkey` **fails**: https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Base64('A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D',true,false)AES_Decrypt(%7B'option':'UTF8','string':'theencryptionkey'%7D,%7B'option':'Base64','string':'1KsM57nT78P5uL8lG0fsxA%3D%3D'%7D,'CBC','Raw','Raw',%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D,%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D)&input=VmU0SGVVL0xFQUtCeW83NkVSSXpOZDRXWUV2allZTEg0c3J4aTJNV1BkST0

Comment: Presumably your key is wrong. [`Crypt::encryptString()`](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Crypt.html#method_encryptString) does not allow the specification of a key (an application key is applied instead), i.e. the key you specified is presumably not used at all. Check with `bin2hex(Crypt::getKey())` which key is applied and if it is a different one, use this key for decryption. *Before you start porting, try to get some clarity on this first!*

Comment: BTW, if a key is to be passed programmatically, it is probably easier to directly use [`Encrypter`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/be2ddb5c31b0b9ebc2738d9f37a9d4c960aa3199/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php#L48) instead of the `Crypt` facade.

Answer (score -1):

I have no experience with the [pointycastle](https://pub.dev/packages/pointycastle) package, however, I have worked with the [encrypt](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt) package in the past.

If you don't mind switching packages you could try the following:

1. Install the package:

`flutter pub add encrypt`

2. Import the package:

`import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';`

3. Create an instance of `Encrypter` with `AESMode.cbc`, because I see that you are using it.

`final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc));`

4. Create an `IV` using one of the constructor options from the documentation of [IV class](https://pub.dev/documentation/encrypt/latest/encrypt/IV-class.html).
5. Create an `Encrypted` instance of your received string from Laravel using one of the constructors from the documentation [Encrypted class](https://pub.dev/documentation/encrypt/latest/encrypt/Encrypted-class.html).
6. Call the decrypt function using the `Encrypted` and `IV` instances you just created:

`final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted, iv: iv);`

I hope this helps.

Comment: what should be the key? `Key.fromBase64` or `Key.fromUtf8 `?

Comment: It depends on what `Crypt::encryptString` returns, did you try both of them?

Comment: `encrypt` is just a thin wrapper over `pointycastle`. In general, it's better to understand what's going on at the lower level, especially when trying to interoperate. (For example, it's not clear from your code above whether you have included any padding removal.)

Answer (score -1):

As noted in the comments, you need to discover how the key is derived in `Crypt`.

Once you have solved that, in `pointycastle` you will almost certainly need to wrap the CBC cipher in a PKCS7 padding cipher (or you will have to remove the padding yourself). It also handles the block-by-block processing for you. Your Dart code for `aesCbcDecrypt` simplifies to:

```
  final cipher = PaddedBlockCipherImpl(
    PKCS7Padding(),
    CBCBlockCipher(AESEngine()),
  )..init(
    false, // decrypt
    PaddedBlockCipherParameters(
      ParametersWithIV(KeyParameter(key), iv),
      null,
    ),
  );

  // a single call to process converts the ciphertext to plaintext (and removes the padding)
  final pt = cipher.process(ct);
```